# How to use map in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
const data = [
    {
        Team : "A",
        Member : "James",
        "Leads" : 305,
        closedLeads : 35
    },
    {
        Team : "C",
        Member : "Mike",
        "Leads" : 305,
        closedLeads : 35
    }
]
```

This is my data and I want to sort them based on their team name in descending order of their Leads. First team name and then all the members within team. And members should be in ascending order of their Leads value.

Comment: you'll want to use sort, not map, to sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const data = [
    {
        Team: "A",
        Member: "James",
        "Leads": 305,
        closedLeads: 35
    },
    {
        Team: "C",
        Member: "Mike",
        "Leads": 305,
        closedLeads: 35
    },
    {
        Team: "C",
        Member: "Mike",
        "Leads": 302,
        closedLeads: 35
    }
];

data.sort((a, b) => (a.Team < b.Team) ? 1 : (a.Team === b.Team) ? ((a.Leads > b.Leads) ? 1 : -1) : -1 );

console.log(data);
```

**`Explanation:`**

You can use the `sort()` method of `Array`.
It takes a callback function which also takes 2 objects as parameters contained in the array (which we can call them as `a` and `b`):

```js
data.sort((a, b) => (a.Team < b.Team) ? 1 : -1);
```

When it returns 1, the function communicates to `sort()` that the `object b` takes precedence in sorting over the `object a`.
Returning -1 would do the reverse.

The callback function can calculate other properties too. When the Team is the same, you can order by a secondary property(Here `Leads`) like this:

```js
data.sort((a, b) => (a.Team < b.Team) ? 1 : (a.Team === b.Team) ? ((a.Leads > b.Leads) ? 1 : -1) : -1 );
```

**Here I have sorted Teams(if they have the same name) in ascending order by comparing their `Leads` value. You can check `Member` instead of `Team` as well.**

Comment: This is the more efficient solution I think

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
    {
        Team : "A",
        Member : "James",
        "Leads" : 305,
        closedLeads : 35
    },
    {
        Team : "C",
        Member : "Mike",
        "Leads" : 305,
        closedLeads : 35
    }
]

const sorted = data
.sort((a, b) => a.Member.localeCompare(b.Meber))
.sort((a, b) => a.Team.localeCompare(b.Team))

console.log(sorted)
```